npm install does not work in virtual studio 1.79
I tried to install react with Node 18.20.12 (x86) in Virtual Studio 1.79 by running the npm command I got from Vite. As a result, it showed three commands that I needed to run (1.cd react 2.npm install 3.npm run dev) and the last one gave me an error:
Error: Failed to load module @rollup/rollup-win32-ia32-msvc. Required DLL was not found. This error usually happens when Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is not installed. You can download it from https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe
-- What do you recommend I do ? I would appreciate it if you could give a source other than https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe.

The error message indicates that the required DLL for the @rollup/rollup-win32-ia32-msvc module was not found. This typically occurs when the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is not installed on your system.
To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

Download Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable: Visit the link provided in the error message (https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe) to download the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable installer.

Install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable: Run the downloaded installer and follow the on-screen instructions to install the redistributable package. This package includes the necessary DLLs required by certain Node.js modules, such as @rollup/rollup.

Retry the npm Command: Once the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is installed, retry running the npm command (npm run dev) to start your React application.


By installing the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable, you should be able to resolve the DLL missing error and successfully run your React application.
